# Difficulty with rewrite rules

Tags: wp-query, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I can't work out how to combine a rewrite rule and a custom query var.

I have created a custom 'edition' template, which calls an external API to populate a table with details of a particular book.

https://wwww.example.com/books/editions

I use a custom query var to populate the database:

https://www.example.com/books/editions/?ed=1950

for example, where ed is a unique identifier, normally the year, for an edition.

How do I rewrite this (using a WordPress function), to:

https://www.example.com/books/editions/1950

I have tried many things from the codex, but with no success! So far:

**Functions.php:**

```
function mr2018_custom_query_vars_filter($vars) {
    $vars[] .= 'ed';
    return $vars;
    }
    add_filter( 'query_vars', 'mr2018_custom_query_vars_filter' );
```

**MyCustomTemplate.php:**

```
$edition = get_query_var( 'ed' );
```

This works: I can use `?ed=1603` in **MyCustomTemplate.php** to call the database. Where I am stuck is rewriting this to something readable, and SEO-friendly.

I believe there are functions which will combine these two processes, but I'm not sure which to use in this instance.

Comment: You've gotten half the way there, I don't believe your query var is necessary though, is this meant to be an archive or is it a post? Keep in mind that adding a custom query var doesn't tell WP what to do with it, you need the logic to make it load your custom template etc in `template_redirect`

Comment: My custom template uses the $edition variable to query an external API using Guzzle and populate a table written in the template file. That works. What I am having difficulty with is rewriting the query string as a pretty URL, so /edition?ed=[query] becomes /edition/[query]

Comment: Also keep in mind you will want to cache those requests at a minimum, remote requests are expensive, you open yourself up to resource exhaustion DOS attacks

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is add a query variable, that's great and necessary for what you're trying to do, but there are 2 more steps to take:

- Making it pretty: Add a rewrite rule to map `/books/edition/xxx` to `index.php?ed=xxx`
- Making it functional: Make it load your custom template so it knows what to do when the user requests `index.php?ed=xxx`

#### Making it Functional

Lets assume the user has arrived at `example.com/?ed=123`. Your filters allow you to use `get_query_var('ed')` but how to load your template?

First we need to make it do things when the `ed` query variable is set, WP won't know what to do on its own:

```
// call render_page() when needed
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_page_template_redirect' );

/**
 * Filter that maps the query variable to a template
 */
function custom_page_template_redirect() {
    global $wp_query;
    if ( ! empty( $wp_query->query_vars['ed'] ) ) {
        // we've found our page, call render_page and exit
        get_template_part( 'ed page template' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

If we're relying on a main query to pull in content, we'll need to do some extra steps to adjust things:

```
// don't pull in a full listing of posts in the main query, there's no need
// ( you can comment this out if you're not using a theme template to render content )
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_page_paging_issue' );
/**
 * fix page loops if pulling in a theme template
 */
function custom_page_paging_issue( $query ) {
    if ( !empty( $query->query_vars['custom_page'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
    }
}
```

#### Making it Pretty

So now `example.com/?ed=123` should work, but as your question described, we want pretty URLs!

This is where rewrite rules come in. Rewrite rules use `add_rewrite_rule`, which needs 2 things:

- A regular expression to match the URL
- A query parameter based url to map what got matched on to

For example, this rewrite rule allows you to use URLs such as `/leaf/22`:

```
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_page_generate_rewrite_rules' );
/**
 * Add our rewrite rules
 */
function custom_page_generate_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $custom_page_rules = array(
        '^leaf/([0-9]+)/?' => 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]'
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $custom_page_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

Note that whenever you change rewrite rules, you have to flush the permalinks. WP won't regenerate the rules automatically. Some people might try to get around this by calling `flush_rewrite_rules` on the `init` hook, but this can cause problems related to the ordering of things, and is very expensive/slow. Simply visiting the permalinks settings page should be enough.

Additionally, it might be tempting to rewrite on to a different URL than `index.php`, or to rewrite on to a pretty permalink. This will not work. Rewrite rules map on to `index.php?key=value` type URLs, anything else will not work. For that you need HTAccess or Nginx rules. Rewrite rules aren't redirects either and can't be used to redirect to different URLs

#### Further Reading

[I wrote about this in greater length here](https://tomjn.com/2013/07/26/content-without-posts/), including a helper class to simplify things.

[I also wrote a post here](https://tomjn.com/2013/04/19/how-wordpress-gets-from-url-to-template/) describing the full process of getting from a URL to a fully loaded page